# How to use useEffect correctly with async changes & navigation involved

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have these 3 variables coming in async to my component (from redux-toolkit).

1. `const appInitialized = useAppSelector(selectAppInitialized)` // takes a few ms for this to become true
2. `const appUser = useAppSelector(selectAppUser)` // userObject, if authenticated. null, if not
3. `const externalLink = useAppSelector(selectExternalLink)` // linkObject, if user used a deep-link to open the app. null, if not

into my main App component.

How do I wait till all 3 are completed and then decide where to navigate the user to? So far this is what I have

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (appInitialized) {
      if (appUser) {
        if (externalLink) {
          // navigate to screen based on externalLink
        } else {
          // navigate to Home screen
        }
      } else {
        if (externalLink) {
          // save the externalLink for navigation after login success 
        }
        // navigate to Login screen
      }
    }
  }, [appInitialized, appUser, externalLink]);
```

But the above is a rudimentary version assuming, appInitialized, appUser, externalLink variables are updated in that exact order.

It fails miserably if the order in which these 3 variables are updated.

**PS:** The above version would've worked if navigation was not involved, I guess.

Comment: What is the problem? your solution works but you are looking for an optimal solution or your code doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

If you put them all in root condition it will be considered as case when all of 3 were initialized, like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      if (appInitialized && appUser && externalLink) {
       // And now when all of 3 were initialized you can do what you want
      }
    }, [appInitialized, appUser, externalLink]);
```

You just simply wait for all 3 to match condition, and when they match you know all of 3 were initialized.